# Mailto with custom subject, body, etc. using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mailto

I'm creating a custom HTML page for my team at work. We are using dropdowns, text fields, and radio buttons to generate the fields of an email. We all use IE and Outlook so that's not a problem. I'm having trouble getting the "generate email" button to fill in the message. I can get the email window to pop up, but all of the fields are blank. I need the `subject`, `to` field, `CC` field, and `body` to be filled in according to the options they selected on the page. Here's my code:

```
<script>
    $(function generateEmail() {
        var emailTo = $("#teamName").val();
        var emailCC = $("#CC").val();
        var emailSubject = "Escalation Request - Ticket #: " + $("#ticketNumber").val();
        var emailBody = "Issue: " + $("#issue") + "<br>Contact info: " + $("#contactInformation") + "<br>Requested action: " + $(".requestedAction:checked");
        window.location.href = "mailto:" + emailTo + "&CC=" + emailCC + "&subject=" + emailSubject + "&body=" + emailBody;
    });
</script>

<body>
    <h1>Team</h1>
    <select id="teamName">
        <option value="a@a.com">Team A</option>
        <option value="b@b.com">Team B</option>
        <option value="c@c.com">Team C</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <h1>CC</h1>
    <input type="text" id="CC"><br><br>
    <h1>Issue</h1>
    <input type="text" id="issue"><br><br>
    <h1>Ticket Number</h1>
    <input type="text" id="ticketNumber"><br><br>
    <h1>Customer contact info</h1>
    <input type="text" id="contactInformation"><br><br>
    <h1>Requested action</h1>
    <input type="radio" name="requestedAction" class="requestedAction" value="Expedite service" id="reqActExpediteService" checked>Expedite service<br>
    <input type="radio" name="requestedAction" class="requestedAction" value="Callback" id="reqActCallback">Callback<br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Generate email" onclick="generateEmail()">
</body>
```

In addition, I also need to format the body with line breaks and bold letters. The code above doesn't work. I'm pretty sure it won't work because of the less than/greater than symbols, but I dunno how else to put in HTML code. I know its possible because the old tool I'm replacing was able to achieve it, I just don't know how. Go easy on me, I'm new to jQuery and Javascript. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have the function inside of a jQuery selector? That is wrong.

Comment: Did you investigate how the old tool did it?

Comment: I tried analyzing the old tool but it's formatted so poorly and it's very convoluted and bloated with unnecessary code. I can't really decode. I dunno why I put the function in a jQuery selector, I think it's because the old code did that. Again, I'm new! Lol.

Comment: Well you do not have a `?` like you re supposed to. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#E-mail_links You do not cancel the click action, you do not escape the user input with encodeURIComponent,

Comment: How would I implement those things?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `?` in the `mailto` url so the querystring parameters are not passed in (note the `?` before `cc=`):

```
window.location.href = "mailto:" + emailTo + "?cc=" + emailCC + "&subject=" + emailSubject + "&body=" + emailBody;
```

To add line breaks you could use `%0A%0A` as a line breakers. This will spawn different paragraphs like so:

```
&body=first line %0A%0A second line
```

You also have some errors in you code, some missing `val()` calls, to get the fields values, and missing conditionals to check if fields are set (to build the query string including those values or not).

```js
function generateEmail() {
  var emailTo = $("#teamName").val();
  var emailCC = $("#CC").val();
  var emailSubject = "Escalation Request - Ticket #: " + $("#ticketNumber").val();
  var emailBody = "Issue: " + $("#issue").val() + "%0A%0AContact info: " + $("#contactInformation").val() + "%0A%0ARequested action: " + $(".requestedAction:checked").val();
  location.href = "mailto:" + emailTo + "?" + 
    (emailCC ? "cc=" + emailCC : "") + 
    (emailSubject ? "&subject=" + emailSubject : "") + 
    (emailBody ? "&body=" + emailBody : "");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Team</h1>
<select id="teamName">
 <option value="a@a.com">Team A</option>
 <option value="b@b.com">Team B</option>
 <option value="c@c.com">Team C</option>
</select><br><br>
<h1>CC</h1>
<input type="text" id="CC"><br><br>
<h1>Issue</h1>
<input type="text" id="issue"><br><br>
<h1>Ticket Number</h1>
<input type="text" id="ticketNumber"><br><br>
<h1>Customer contact info</h1>
<input type="text" id="contactInformation"><br><br>
<h1>Requested action</h1>
<input type="radio" name="requestedAction" class="requestedAction" value="Expedite service" id="reqActExpediteService" checked>Expedite service<br>
<input type="radio" name="requestedAction" class="requestedAction" value="Callback" id="reqActCallback">Callback<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Generate email" onclick="generateEmail()">
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I do that, it puts "&subject=Escalation Request - Ticket #: " in the CC field and doesn't populate anything else.

Comment: @brianwantsblood check it now. WOrking snippet added.

Comment: Your updated code snippit works, but it still puts "&subject=Escalation Request - Ticket #: " in the CC field, and the subject is blank (I can't for the life of me figure out why). The to and body fields are populated though.

Comment: @brianwantsblood it's seems related to the data. Can you add some sample data, to test it against it?

Comment: it works when i put data in but not if the CC field is blank. i can just make an if statement, i guess. weird. thanks for your help!

Comment: @brianwantsblood i added some conditionals. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function generateEmail() {
  var emailTo = $("#teamName").val();
  var emailCC = $("#CC").val();
  var emailSubject = "Escalation Request - Ticket #: " + $("#ticketNumber").val();
  var emailBody = "Issue: " + $("#issue").val() + "%0A%0AContact info: " + $("#contactInformation").val() + "%0A%0ARequested action: " + $(".requestedAction:checked").val();
  location.href = "mailto:" + emailTo + "?" + 
    (emailCC ? "cc=" + emailCC : "") + 
    (emailSubject ? "&subject=" + emailSubject : "") + 
    (emailBody ? "&body=" + emailBody : "");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Team</h1>
<select id="teamName">
 <option value="a@a.com">Team A</option>
 <option value="b@b.com">Team B</option>
 <option value="c@c.com">Team C</option>
</select><br><br>
<h1>CC</h1>
<input type="text" id="CC"><br><br>
<h1>Issue</h1>
<input type="text" id="issue"><br><br>
<h1>Ticket Number</h1>
<input type="text" id="ticketNumber"><br><br>
<h1>Customer contact info</h1>
<input type="text" id="contactInformation"><br><br>
<h1>Requested action</h1>
<input type="radio" name="requestedAction" class="requestedAction" value="Expedite service" id="reqActExpediteService" checked>Expedite service<br>
<input type="radio" name="requestedAction" class="requestedAction" value="Callback" id="reqActCallback">Callback<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Generate email" onclick="generateEmail()">
```